# Is it possible to pass an environment variable to VM Instance start up script using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Python in a cloud function to switch on a VM instance when the function is triggered.

```
     request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
     response = request.execute()
```

The VM instance will in turn run a start up script when it starts up.

However, is it possible to pass an environment variable to the start up script in the above Python command. If so, how would I do it?

I am planning on having a conditional in my instance start up script which does something like:

if env variable is 'x':

```
run python script x.py
```

else:

```
run python script y.py
```

etc...

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider the custom attribute on a VM instead of Environment Variable? (Or create a script that read the custom attribute and put the value in env var if you prefer). https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview#guest_attributes

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't be able to directly set an environment variable, but you could you a Metadata parameter for your VM. Here's how you could do it:

1. Modify the metadata set of your VM before turning it on. [Here's how.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata)
2. Start the VM.
3. In your startup script, query the metadata server to retrieve the value you configured in step 1. [How to retrieve metadata values?](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata)
4. Treat the retrieved value like if it was environment variable.

I hope this helps you achieve your goal :)

EDIT: [Guest attributes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/manage-guest-attributes) suggested in the comment by
guillaume blaquiere would work the same way, they are just a part of the instance metadata.